# Send email to all the records in the table using where condition in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, email, laravel-5, sendmail

I am novice to laravel.I need to send email to all the records in the table using where condition(where exam_id=1). Each record will get the email message is name and email of its own.Already stored in the table.Can any own suggest for this?

Advance thanks

```
       public function sendmail(Request $request) {

        $email = DB::table('student')->select('email','exam_id')->where('exam_id','=','1')->get();
          $email= mysql_query("SELECT email FROM student WHERE exam_id='1' ;"); 
           $title = $request->input('title');
           $content = $request->input('content');
      if(mysql_num_rows($email))
        {
         while($elist_result = mysql_fetch_array($email))
            {
           Mail::send('email', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content],function ($message) 
             {
             $message->from('dhivya@authorselvi.com', 'dhivya');
             $message->to('dhivya@authorselvi.com');
                $message->cc($elist_result);
            $message->subject("Hello");

             }  );
               }
          }
             return response()->json(['message' => 'message send successfully']);
              }
```

Comment: Share your efforts as in code. One simple approach would be storing query result in an object and looping over it.

Comment: i included my code Mr.Shubhamoy Chakrabarty.Thanks for your reply.Please suggest for me

Comment: What error are you encountering? It seems that your code is just right though with minor modifications like using PDO or mysqli_* instead of mysql_* (since this is already deprecated in PHP7).

Comment: ErrorException in HomeController.php line 277: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead   //i got this error Mr.ronald

Comment: i changed mysql to PDO.Now i got error as :Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\PDO_query()

Comment: i changed mysql to mysqli.Now i got error :ErrorException in HomeController.php line 277: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: How to send the mail to all records in the database table using laravel.Please suggest me

Comment: @DhivyaPriya, kindly upvote my comment since that helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```html
public function sendmail(Request $request) {

        $email = DB::table('student')->select('email','exam_id')->where('exam_id','=','1')->get();

        $title = $request['title'];
        $content = $request['content'];


        foreach($email as $email) {
           Mail::send('email', ['title' => $title, 'content' =>   $content],function ($message) 
             {
             $message->from('dhivya@authorselvi.com', 'dhivya');
             $message->to($email->email);
             $message->subject("Hello");

             });
        }

     return response()->json(['message' => 'message send successfully']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you are sticked to **clear PHP** and it's wrong while you are working on Laravel framework.

```
public function sendmail(Request $request) {

        $emails = DB::table('student')->select('email','exam_id')->where('exam_id','=','1')->get();

        $title = $request['title'];
        $content = $request['content'];


        foreach($emails as $email) {
           Mail::send('email', ['title' => $title, 'content' =>   $content],function ($message) 
             {
             $message->from('dhivya@authorselvi.com', 'dhivya');
             $message->to($email->email);
             $message->subject("Hello");

             });
        }

     return response()->json(['message' => 'message send successfully']);
}
```

Take a look at your code edited by me and try it.

Comment: ErrorException in HomeController.php line 336: Undefined variable: email //I got this error

Comment: Check out the edited code, a little mistake occured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.forexknight .I tried your code but i got error above mentioned

Comment: I'm telling you that I've edited the code, so copy it and check again.

Comment: Can you provide your full function? If yes copy it to a fiddle, then I will check it.

Comment: i dont know how to do this in fiddle sorry